# Android project in Eclipse project that works in both windows and linux

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cross-platform, adt

My current Android development environment is comprised of Eclipse projects that are located on a Windows share (Samba/CIFS actually).

This allows me to switch from one workstation to another without having to sync or check-out files.

As long as all machines were Windows only (XP, 7) this setup works great, but now I would like to develop from an Ubuntu 10.04 machines as well.

I managed to setup my Ubuntu 10.04 system with the latest Eclipse Indigo (3.7.1), accessing the workspace on the shared Samba volume.

It works well, but this forces me to change the `SDK Location` field in `Android Preferences` (Window > Preferences > Android). This is because the Android SDK path is different on a Windows system (usually `C:\android-sdk-windows`) from the one on a Linux system (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/android-sdk-linux`).

Any ideas how to "perfect-ize" this setup so that I don't have to change even that?

For example, one possibility would be to put the Android SDK on the Windows share, too, but:

1. The path notations are different even then (backslash vs. forward
   slash, etc.)
2. Build would become even slower than what it is currently.

Another possibility is to see whether the environment variable %ANDROID_HOME% can be creatively used for this purpose.

**UPDATE:** Attempting to use %ANDROID_HOME% on the Windows side, results in `Value must be an existing directory` error and won't even enable the `OK` button to save this. It looks like what I am trying to accomplish isn't possible.

Comment: ANDROID_HOME is your best option, if it can be utilized for that at all. I personally would rather keep the configuration as it is, at this point.

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to configure/setup your multiple IDEs to work with a particular project, instead, you should make your project work with multiple IDEs. Consider using ant or maven to make your project portable cross different IDE environment. I use maven with my Android project cross Mac and Windows, everything from project setup to build/release are seamless cross all my IDE environments.

Comment: @hovanessyan +1 for the environment variable idea. Unfortunately, Eclipse won't accept an env var in that `SDK Location` edit box. Instead, it issues an error message: `Value must be an existing directory`. It turns out that Eclipse is smart, but not smart enough.

Comment: @yorkw These aren't multiple IDEs. It's only one IDE: Eclipse.